# Create a path to node/add in twig

Tags: theming, 8, routes

Can I use the path() function in twig to create a link to a non-node entity add form. Taking the group module as an example, if I want to create a link to the 'group/add' page in twig can I use something like:

```
{{ path('entity.group.add') }}
```

I know that the above does not work, neither does

```
{{ path('group.add') }}
```

Not sure if there is a way to do this with the various twig functions that create links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to According to [Functions - In Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates) just Try

```
{{ path('node.add', {'node_type' : 'yourcontenttypename'}) }}
```

as the example for article content type

```
{{ path('node.add', {'node_type' : 'article'}) }}
```

**Update**
Try

```
{{ path('entity.group.add_form', {'group_type' : 'yourgrouptype' }) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried something similar for 'groups' and it did not work. So whilst that works for entities of type 'node' - I do not think it works for other/custom entities. I have updated my question to specify that I am asking about non-node entities.

Comment: Thanks again. `{{ path('entity.group_type.edit_form', {'group_type' : 'yourgruoptype'  }) }}` results in '/admin/group/types/manage/organisation'.

Comment: But you did give me an idea, and it is working with `{{ path('entity.group.add_form', {'group_type' : 'yourgrouptype'  }) }}`

Comment: Will mark as accepted answer since you got me most of the way there. Will you update with the one from above so if anyone else is looking for this they see answer in your comment? Thanks again!

Comment: @bletch you're welcome I add  it to answer for future guys visits this question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for 'add feed' path in twig.

```
{{ path('entity.feeds_feed.add_form', {'feeds_feed_type' : '<FEED_NAME>' }) }}"
```